# 'flask run' working in one conda env but not another

Tags: python, flask, conda

`flask run` won't work when I try it in a new conda env but works fine in an older conda env.

I've deleted and recreated `new-env` and reinstalled flask with the same version: 1.0.3.

```
(new-env) C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\myproject\backend>set FLASK_APP=my_app.py

(new-env) C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\myproject\backend>set FLASK_DEBUG=1

(new-env) C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\myproject\backend>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "my_app.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
c:\users\myname\anaconda3\envs\new-env\python.exe: No module named C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\envs\new-env\Scripts\flask
```

Switching to older conda env:

```
(old-env) C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\myproject\backend>flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: It is not clear what is missing in the (new-env), but something is not working there. Try to create ".flaskenv" file and add the following inside : FLASK_APP=my_app.py
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=1 , then "flask run"

Comment: Check the exact build number and the channel from which flask was installed in both environments.